# how to delete the columns in dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df2000.drop('jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec').show()
```

[image]

now it's showing without deleted columns in dataframe

[image]

```
df2000.show()
```

when i run the show command alone to check the table .but comes with deleted column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drop` is not a side-effecting function. it returns a new Dataframe with specified columns removed. so you would have assign the new dataframe to a value to be referenced later as shown below.

```
>>> df2000 = spark.createDataFrame([('a',10,20,30),('a',10,20,30),('a',10,20,30),('a',10,20,30)],['key', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar'])
>>> cols = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar']
>>> df2000.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|key|jan|feb|mar|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a| 10| 20| 30|
|  a| 10| 20| 30|
|  a| 10| 20| 30|
|  a| 10| 20| 30|
+---+---+---+---+

>>> cols = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar']
>>> df2000_dropped_col = reduce(lambda x,y: x.drop(y),cols,df2000)
>>> df2000_dropped_col.show()
+---+
|key|
+---+
|  a|
|  a|
|  a|
|  a|
+---+
```

now doing a `show` on the new dataframe will yield the desired result with all the month columns dropped.

Comment: can you try  this? `df2000_dropped_cols = df2000.drop('jan', 'feb', 'mar')`?

Comment: Yeah. I tried this. It's not working. Df2000_dropped_cols is assigning..

Comment: Yeah I tried this. It's not working. Df2000_dropped_cols is not assigning

Comment: >>> df2000_dropped_cols.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'

Comment: but when i do this df2000_dropped_cols = df2000.drop('jan', 'feb', 'mar') results shows as per our expectation. after that to check this df2000_dropped_cols DF . its throw df2000_dropped_cols.show() Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show' –

Comment: it seems df2000_dropped_cols is assigned a value of None not a dataframe. I have updated the answer with exact step to follow. can you confirm if you did that?

Comment: yeah i did that. I'm not getting the answer

Comment: >>>from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

>>> reduce(DataFrame.drop, ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'], df2000)

DataFrame[KOF: string, total0: bigint]

>>>df2000.show()

DataFrame[KOF: string, jan: bigint, feb: bigint, mar: bigint, apr: bigint, may: bigint, jun: bigint, jul: bigint, aug: bigint, sep: bigint, oct: bigint, nov: bigint, dec: bigint, total0: bigint]
same problem. don't know ..why

Comment: >>> from pyspark.sql import column
>>> drop_list = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']
>>> df2000.select([column for column in df2000.columns if column not in drop_list])
DataFrame[KOF: string, total0: bigint]
>>> df2000
DataFrame[KOF: string, jan: bigint, feb: bigint, mar: bigint, apr: bigint, may: bigint, jun: bigint, jul: bigint, aug: bigint, sep: bigint, oct: bigint, nov: bigint, dec: bigint, total0: bigint]
I have tried this alternate way also columns are back. :-(

Comment: :D Perfect Man :-)

Comment: i ticked it. what it does? because im new to stackoverflow